# Jquery PrintMe Plugin Css Style not included

Tags: javascript, jquery, frontend

I'm trying to print my div with PrintMe plugin.
Everything works perfect except for including CSS..

Here's the link of the usage.

[PrintMe ReadMe page](https://github.com/menusal/printMe/blob/master/README.md)

And below is what I have in my index.php code.

```
$("#print").click(function(){
  $("#articleonly").printMe({ "path": ["ArticleStyle.css"] });
});
```

ArticleStyle.css is located at the same directory as the index.php file.

Css File code is as below.

```
.print_en {
  font-family: 'EB Garamond', serif;
  font-size: 18px;
}
.print_ko {
  font-family: 'KoPub Batang', serif;
  font-size: 17px;
  line-height: 1.8;
  letter-spacing: -1px;
  font-weight: 100;
}
#article_title {
  text-indent: 5px;
}
```

I thought maybe I have to import Web-font at CSS, but other properties don't seem to work anyway.

And below is the div I'm trying to print with CSS.

```
<div id="articleonly" class="print_<?php echo $lang; ?>">
  <?php
    //Title
    echo "<h1 id='article_title'>".htmlspecialchars($article["$title"])."</h1>";
    //Contents
    echo $article["$contents"]."</br>";
    //Author
    // echo "Author :".$article["name"];
  ?>
</div>
```

p.s. I tried putting ./ and / at the path and getting off [] from the path..
Even tried modifying the printme.js file to just load the css file directly.

If anyone can help, I'd be forever in your debt!

Comment: Can you show us the code for `printMe` ?

Comment: Do you mean the original PrintMe Code?
Below is the link to that.
https://github.com/menusal/printMe/blob/master/jquery-printme.js

Answer (score 0):

You can try giving the absolute path of ArticleStyle.css instead of relative path.

```
$("#print").click(function(){
  $("#articleonly").printMe({ "path": ["http://absolute-path/ArticleStyle.css"] });
});
```

Do replace absolute-path with the path to css.

Comment: Thanks for your answer,
I tried it but seems the problem is with the web font.
Maybe web font won't be applied to when I print?

Comment: @PeterKim you need font-face for using new fonts. You can follow this link: http://www.miltonbayer.com/font-face/